# Shortcuts to SE sites do not work

Tags: bug

The last few days the links like [SE.Linux], [SE.ElementaryOS], etc. do not work in comments for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) the format is:

```
[Linux.se] and  [ElementaryOS.se]
```

> [something.se] – link to something.stackexchange.com, if that site
>   exists. Link text is the site name. Use [ubuntu.se] for Ask Ubuntu.
>   [meta.something.se] links to the meta site.

Comment: [Linux.se] and  [ElementaryOS.se]

Comment: I used to do it in reverse order and it worked. This way will do.

Comment: The link is broken in the answer.

Comment: @Pilot6 - thanks! fixed

Comment: @Pilot6 are you sure? I've always used the `sitename.se` format and have never seen the inverse.

Comment: @terdon Now I am not 100% sure, but I did that automatically. Hm, maybe I have some mental problem...